# Configuring Travel Modes in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, multimodal-network

I am a new user of ArcGis and I am trying to do the exercises provided on the ESRI website for Network Analyst (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-2-creating-a-multimodal-network-dataset.htm).

When doing the second exercise, after configuring the PedestrianTime evaluator I should configure the Travel Modes, but I don't get any window with this, and instead it jumps to the part from where I can configure directions.

How do I get the window needed for Travel Modes?

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots of what you have done and maybe we can better assess the situation that way?

Comment: @Benjamin_Marosites If you have an answer, you can comment and vote to reopen or flag the question for moderator review. Editing the question to contain your answer breaks the Q/A model, and should be avoided.